# Origin of phrase "open-and-shut" as in "it's not an open-and-shut case"

Tags: phrases, etymology, idioms

I used the phrase "open-and-shut" today, as in, "It's not an open-and-shut case", meaning that the item under discussion has not been decided and the outcome is not obvious.

I don't think I've ever heard the positive, only the negative. "It's not an open-and-shut case" seems to be the idiomatic way to use the phrase. I'm curious:

1. What's the origin of "open-and-shut"?
2. What's the origin of the idiomatic usage, "not an open-and-shut case"?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=open-and-shut&searchmode=none):

> *Open-and-shut* "simple, straightforward" first recorded 1841 in New Orleans.

No further information on the origin of this phrase is available from the other sources I checked.

*Open-and-shut* is certainly used in the positive sense. In fact, *open-and-shut case* is a common expression. Two examples:

> - [An Open-and-Shut Issue on Cruise Ships](http://www.cruisecritic.com/news/news.cfm?ID=4370)
> - [An open-and-shut case](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/dec/19/opinion/la-ed-dcfs-20101219)
> - [Golf's host clubs have open-and-shut policies on discrimination](http://www.usatoday.com/sports/golf/2003-04-09-club-policies_x.htm)

And I also discovered that this phrase (*open-and-shut*) is extremely popular in golfing circles (think *Open*) with the hyphens dropped (*open and shut* or *Open and shut*). Examples (headlines):

> - [Some Open and shut Rules cases](http://davidhbarrett.com/golf/golf/personalities/207/some-open-and-shut-rules-cases/)
> - [The Open and shut case: Louis Oosthuizen shows the charm of a front-runner...](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/golf/article-1295796/MARTIN-SAMUEL-The-Open-shut-case-Louis-Oosthuizen-shows-charm-runner-join-golfs-history-men.html)
> - [It’s an Open and shut case for Gallo](http://www.middletownpress.com/articles/2010/07/28/sports/doc4c50d72807da5805255587.txt)
> - [The gospel according to Gulbis: Open and shut](http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/blog/devil_ball_golf/post/The-gospel-according-to-Gulbis-Open-and-shut?urn=golf-175511)
> - [Woods wins first Open and Shut Championship](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/golf/woods-wins-first-open-and-shut-championship-708692.html)

Comment: The 1841 usage is from the newspaper the _Picayune_ (OED) and is "The contest between _Humming Bird_ and _Maria Collier_ was considered all but a ‘dead open and shut game’."

Comment: @mgkrebbs: Wow, awesome find. You should post this as an answer!

Comment: Yes, Google Ngrams finds several references to "open and shut case" in the 1800s.  One suspects that the term didn't "take off" until movies popularized it, though.

Comment: Looking further, "dead open and shut" was [extraordinarily popular in the 1800s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Open+and+shut+case%2C+dead+open+and+shut&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2COpen%20and%20shut%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdead%20open%20and%20shut%3B%2Cc0").  Looking at the references, most are from a (widely copied) book of biblical commentary by Joseph Hall, but the later ones appear to refer to games (probably poker).